# Webresource.axd over ssl (in iis ssl is required)

Tags: iis, crm, webresource.axd

Is it possible to define a Webresource.axd (in my case it's the cache.axd of crm) over https?

I have a site in the iis with ssl required and two bindings 8080 fot http and 444 for https

I can't brows to http://domain:8080/cache.axd or https://domain:444/cache.axd

Please help
Thank you in advanced